# Customizing responsive navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

it is my first time using flex and I tried to make a responsive navbar and it is success in a way. Things I want to do:

1. Make the hamburger icon turn to X with smooth transition.
2. Make the menu opening with smooth slide down transition (instead of instant showing).
3. Add [ border-bottom: 1px solid black; ] to .social-icons when the menu is opened (active).
4. Add [ border-radius: 0; ] to .social-icons ul li:first-child when the menu is opened (active).

I've tried many things, watched many tutorials but I can't make it. Here is the code:

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not expect people to finish your code off, especially when it is something simple as HTML & CSS.

First of all I am going to explain it how you can accomplish 3rd and 4th problem that you have.

When you click hamburger icon to show menu, it adds 'active' class name to 'navbar-links'.
Therefore you need to make something like this to accomplish what you want.

```
.navbar-links.active .social-icons{
    ...your style goes here..
}
```

How this works is that you are selecting elements that have both navbar-links and active as their class names. After that selector you are selecting child elements that have social-icons class name.

To make smooth animations when you open menu and when it resizes, I recommend you looking into [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) where you can see how animations work.
Just add animation to hamburgers class name and as soon as it gets that class name it will make an animation that you designed.

Look at it this way, when you declare animation for a class, as soon as an element gets that class it will run an animation.
For instance you can do something like this :

CSS :

```
.toggle-button{
   opacity: 0.5;
   color : white;
}
.active_toggle_button{
   animation : customAnimation 0.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes customAnimation {
  to{
      opacity: 1;
      color : green;
    }
  }
```

And in your Javascript :

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active');
  toggleButton.classList.toggle('active_toggle_button');
})
```

This will toggle "active_toggle_button" class to your hamburger when you click it. As soon as it adds this class to your hamburger it will do the animation.
As I said, look into the link I gave you from w3schools. This is just general idea to let you know how it actually works.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did fix 3 and 4 but i can't animate the dropdown animation for the navbar. Tried it as well if you can give me some tip i will appreciate it.